# Removing a member from an AD group using net-ldap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, active-directory, ldap

What is the proper methodology (the steps) to remove an user from an AD group? In this context, I'm doing it from within a Rails project, using net-ldap gem.

Originally, I was going to modify the "memberof" value for the user (remove that particular group from the array of grouop DN's in the "memberof" field), but I learned that "memberof" is read-only.

I'm kind of new to the concept of LDAP, so I'm not sure what the standard practices are.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is over a year old, but I am posting for posterity's sake since this shows up when searching for removing users from a group in Active Directory using Ruby net-ldap.

```
@ldap.open do |ldap|
  ldap.modify :dn => "CN=your group,OU=something,DC=domain,DC=org", :operations => [[:delete, :member, "CN=Johnny Doe,OU=something,DC=domain,DC=org"]]
end
```

There are two "gotchas". First with Active Directory you cannot manage a user's groups, you can only manage a group's membership. Second, the ":operations" must be an array of operation tuples.